# How to add menuItem to actionbarsherlock dialog?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using Theme `Theme.Sherlock.Dialog` tho show a dialog. Now, how can I add menu items at the top right corner of that dialog?
I use this code but I can't.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Close")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.button_close)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. The action bar of the dialog has none of the features of the normal action bar.

Words of the ActionBarSherlock developer in this [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/cY0CyLmFUGs).

Answer (score 0):

please check if you are setting holo theme correctly and make sure you have initialized the actionbar in oncreate of activity. Above code works fine if you have followed the steps correctly